# Missing search results

Tags: 2013, search, sharepoint-standard

I have this query `contentclass:STS_Site Path:{Site.Url}* Site<>{Site.Url}`
  I have at least 20 site collections that should be returned but only 4 are returned.  I have check that the display limit is at 25 and that the sites that are not appearing are not excluded from Search.  Has anyone else encoutered this issue?  I wanting to create a landing page that shows the sites that the users have access to.

Comment: Why do you have Path and Site in the query? Have you tried contentClass=STS_Site? Do you have access to all the sites?

Comment: Path:{Site.Url}* Site<>{Site.Url} is to ignore the current site in the search results.  I do have access to all sites.

Comment: What do you get with my shorter query above?

Comment: I get more sites but from other web applications Path:{Site.Url}* limits to the current web app and  Site<>{Site.Url} ignores the current site where the query is being run from.

Comment: I am asking if it includes your missing sites.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that.  No it doesn't.  It shows the site that I saw before I removed  
Path:{Site.Url}* Site<>{Site.Url}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42116/discussion-between-matthew-mcdermott-and-mike-blair).